# Documentation for automark

Tags: koma-script

Where do I find the documentation for automark?

Did a search for the word `automark` at here: http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf

Not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the the manual `scrguien.pdf`, Chapter 5: "Adapting Page Headers and Footers with scrlayer-scrpage", **pages 242 ff**.

[image: page 242]